# Separating designer from XAML window for WPF in VS2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I don't see a button to separate the designer window from the XAML window for WPF in Visual Studio 2010.

I've got three screens, and I want both a full screen XAML window and a full screen designer window.

Comment: I got a question, how do you hook up 3 monitors to your machine? haven't googled it yet.

Comment: 2 screens on a Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT and one on a Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS.

Comment: thanks, I wonder if you can do this on the laptops without replacing Video cards....anyhow, see my answer below!

Comment: I think for the most mainstream laptops its only possible to add one additional screen, but i´m not sure about that.

Comment: @VoodooChild It might be a bit late (and off topic), but there are usb video cards that you can use to hook up additional monitors to your laptop. Just search for "usb video card" at Amazon (or your online store).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

1. Open your XAML file as usual.
2. In the solution explorer, right-click on your XAML file and choose "Open with...", then "Source Code (Text) Editor", then OK.

You should now have two tabs for your XAML file, one in design view and one in code view. At this point, you can drag one of them onto your second monitor while leaving the other in place.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are my hero! 
Thanks, searched the web for days, dont want to start a question for this stupid task.

Comment: this is easily the tip of the year.  It also works for Windows Phone 7 dev.

Comment: Thanks VoodooChild. It's a shame they didn't just support separation of the designer/xaml tabs out of the box with a command button.

Comment: This works, but the only issue is that you lose the ability to click on a control in the designer and have it automatically highlight it in the XAML, and vice versa.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is the best way:
"If your goal is multi-monitor with code on the right and design surface on the left (for instance), then you can maximize VS2010 across both screens, set the splitter to be VERTICAL (there are buttons in the splitter bar that let you do this), then place the splitter at the join between the two screens (quickest approach)"

from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-the-wpf-and-silverlight-designer-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx#tip10

Hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: I must say, even though it looks ugly (and I can't maximize VS cross-monitor, only resize it), but sometimes it is more efficient than the solution in accepted answer. Because I want the xaml code and designer synchronized: when I click one control in the designer it is navigated to the corresponding part in xaml, and vice versa. This is helpful when you have a really complex xaml file.

Comment: Agree with all. What a time to be alive.