# Is it possible to separate the XAML page into designer and xaml windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am coding up a Windows Phone 7 app and as large as my screen is, I'd like to separate the designer from the XAML coding window and throw it onto another screen.

Possible?

Comment: 30".  That's where visual studio starts to become usable; 30 glorious inches.

Comment: See my answer in [Separating designer from xaml window for wpf in vs2010][1]


[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112561/separating-designer-from-xaml-window-for-wpf-in-vs2010/3112639#3112639

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if you double click on the "XAML" or "Design" tabs in-between the two panes it will maximize that tab and you can then use the tabs to switch back and forth between design view and XAML view.

Hope this helps

Edit: If you want to go back to split pane view there are three very small icons at the bottom right and you can click one of those to either split vertically or horizontally.  The one with the double arrows will also let you switch back and forth between single and split pane views.

[image: Here is what I'm talking about]

Edit: I found [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514553(v=VS.100).aspx) which makes it seem that they had the split view so that

> ...if you drag a control from the
>   Toolbox to Design view, the XAML is
>   immediately updated to reflect the new
>   element. Likewise, if a new element is
>   added by typing the markup in XAML
>   view, the visual representation will
>   appear in Design view immediately,
>   once the XAML is correctly formed.

Edit 3: Looks like someone found an answer before. You may want to try this:
[Separating designer from XAML window for WPF in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112561/separating-designer-from-xaml-window-for-wpf-in-vs2010/3112639#3112639)

Comment: Not exactly what I want.  I'd like to able to edit XAML and see changes reflected in real time (like it does in split screen mode), yet have windows on separate screens.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to another post.

Comment: The link in edit 3 works for me!

Comment: This is NOT a solution as the XAML and Design are not *fully* synced as they are in split view.